# React: first string return undefined in form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm triying to do a search function but the action only works when I type the second string.

```
const handleSearch = () => {
        console.log(search)
        dispatch(searchClient(search));
    }
```

For exemple I type ben
The first letter from search return undefined and the second return "b", always one string later.

Here my return

```
<div onChange={() => handleSearch()}>
                <Input
                placeholder="Client…"
                onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: I would assume that `handleSearch` is called before the state was updated because you are calling it in response to input field changing and not in response to the state changing. So `handleSearch` would always use the previous state. Maybe you want to use `useEffect` instead of binding the `handleSearch` function to the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the `useEffect` hook that will trigger the `searchClient` whenever `search` is updated. so it's guaranteed to be called with the current version of `search`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(searchClient(search));
}, [search])

return (
  <div>
    <Input 
      placeholder="Client…" 
      onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
);
```